# How can I combine two JSON feeds into Angular Bootstrap UI typeahead?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Angular and Angular UI Bootstrap I need to combine results from 2 feeds into a single typeahead dropdown. I will combine results from the Google places JSON feed with results from my application, into a single set of Typeahead dropdown results.

Is this possible to combine both feeds in a promise? I have tried using the $q method, but I can't seem to get this working. This is what I've tried so far. Non-working JS Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfnegz60/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="dr" ng-controller="testCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getCombinedLocations($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">

    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('dr', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $q) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.getCombinedLocations = function(val) { $q.all(['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json','http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json']).then(function(results){

       // return results;
    $scope.combined = [];
    angular.forEach(results, function(result){
      $scope.combined.push(result.data);
        return  $scope.combined;
    });
        })}    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing not just a URL but a whole `$http.get` request to the Promise. See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfnegz60/3/

```
 $q.all([$http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }),$http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    })])
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and I can see some data coming back now, but the fiddle is still throwing errors. Also the second call appears to be coming back with results undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: but what should be the URLs ? in your example they were the same - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

Comment: The second JSON service is not going to be available for a day or so.. and I couldn't find any other public feed to test quickly..

Comment: I think it's a it outside the question scope... you were asking for a way to combine 2 API calls in promise. to test it works - you could put 1 or both JSON files with model data somewhere,

Comment: Ok, I'll test with a static JSON file. But, shouldn't the 'results2' in your example fiddle also have data returned, at the moment it comes back undefined in the console trace? Is this because if the URL is the same and the Google API doesn't respond to the second call?

Comment: let me know what will be the result with static JSON. seems that result2 undefined - it's not your code problem. If second call failed you would get $q.all rejected - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all